# Touchpad recognised as USB OPTICAL MOUSE

Tags: 12.10, touchpad

I Installed ubuntu **12.10** on a **Dell Vostro 1710** (yes, this is old hardware ;-).

Everything works great except for the touchpad ! (wifi see [here](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.fr/2012/07/broadcom-wireless-fix-for-ubuntu-1210.html))

The touchpad doesn't work at all, and is recognised as "USB OPTICAL MOUSE" :

**Vostro1710:~$ xinput list**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Webcam                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**Vostro1710:~$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices**

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=15d9 Product=0a4d Version=0111
N: Name=" USB OPTICAL MOUSE"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10
```

I followed logging instructions on [this pag](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)e, so you can read my [evtest](http://share.vbonhomme.fr/opensource/evtest) as well as my [Xorg.0.log](http://share.vbonhomme.fr/opensource/Xorg.0.log.txt).

Thanks folks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My laptop was having this same problem. I followed [this solution](http://www.softwaretalk.info/touch-pad-of-laptop-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-occasionally.htm):

It was as simple as doing the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Editing this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to be this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
```

then I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I then rebooted the computer, and everything has been working fine.